# Failed to convert property value of type 'com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory' to required type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory'

Tags: spring, jms, ibm-mq, jmstemplate

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'XMqJmsTemplate' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-XMq.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory' to required type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' for property 'connectionFactory'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory] to required type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] for property 'connectionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found.
```

My `pom.xml` has only `spring-jms3.2.14.RELEASE`, so no chance of conflicts.
Not able to solve this issue when deploying to Tomcat 8.0V.

Is there any jar which can resolve the conversion issue?

Comment: After resolving the conflicts with jms didn't resolved the issue. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: its just the dependency conflict issue.

Comment: Can you explain the steps to resoolve the dependency conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by using the Maven Dependency listed below:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>SPRING-JMS-VERSION</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
            <version>VERSION</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the value for SPRING-JMS-VERSION and  VERSION

Comment: @GGHOSH : You can use any latest spring-jms-version, it should work. for ibm-all-client, you will need to use above 9.0